# Como enviar um parcelable de um objeto com list?

Tags: android

Estou tentando enviar um objeto para uma `activity` usando `parcelable`, acontece que o objeto é enviado mas as listas que estão dentro dele chegam vazias...

Classe que contém as listas:
(Eu tentei resolver o problema usando o gerador de parceable do Android Studio, ele gerou isso e as linhas que comentei, porém não funcionou, então eu adicionei o que está comentando com #)

```
public class Recipes implements Parcelable {

    public static final String RECIPES_URL = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/5907926b_baking/baking.json";

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int servings;
    private String image;
    private List<Ingredients> ingredientsList;
    private List<Steps> stepsList;
    public static final String PARCEABLE_KEY = "RECIPES_KEY";

    protected Recipes(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        servings = in.readInt();
        image = in.readString();
        ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>(); //#
        in.readList(ingredientsList, List.class.getClassLoader()); //#
        stepsList = new ArrayList<>(); //#
        in.readList(stepsList, List.class.getClassLoader()); //#
        /*ingredientsList = in.createTypedArrayList(Ingredients.CREATOR);
        stepsList = in.createTypedArrayList(Steps.CREATOR);*/
    }

    public Recipes(){}

    public static final Creator<Recipes> CREATOR = new Creator<Recipes>() {
        @Override
        public Recipes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Recipes(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Recipes[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Recipes[size];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getServings() {
        return servings;
    }

    public void setServings(int servings) {
        this.servings = servings;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<Ingredients> getIngredientsList() {
        return ingredientsList;
    }

    public void setIngredientsList(List<Ingredients> ingredientsList) {
        this.ingredientsList = ingredientsList;
    }

    public List<Steps> getStepsList() {
        return stepsList;
    }

    public void setStepsList(List<Steps> stepsList) {
        this.stepsList = stepsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(servings);
        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeTypedList(ingredientsList);
        dest.writeTypedList(stepsList);
    }
}
```

Os objetos da lista: (implementei parcelables nelas para tentar solucionar o problema)

```
public class Ingredients extends Recipes implements Parcelable {
    private int quantity;
    private String measure;
    private String ingredient;

    protected Ingredients(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public Ingredients() {}

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getMeasure() {
        return measure;
    }

    public void setMeasure(String measure) {
        this.measure = measure;
    }

    public String getIngredient() {
        return ingredient;
    }

    public void setIngredient(String ingredient) {
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }
}

public class Steps extends Recipes implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String description;
    private String videoUrl;
    private String thumbnailUrl;

    public Steps() {}

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

Não posso usar `serializable`, tem que ser `parcelable`!

**UPDATE:**
Ao debugar, notei que ingredientsList sempre vem com size 38, porém tudo vazio, enquanto que stepsList vem com size 0... Não importanto qual item eu selecione! (ao clicar em um item de uma recycleview, é enviado para outra actvity o objeto deste item, que no caso é Recipes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi removendo as partes com comentário e adicionando `in.readTypedList(ingredientsList, Ingredients.CREATOR);` no construtor

```
public class Recipes implements Parcelable {

    public static final String RECIPES_URL = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/5907926b_baking/baking.json";

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int servings;
    private String image;
    private List<Ingredients> ingredientsList;
    private List<Steps> stepsList;
    public static final String PARCEABLE_KEY = "RECIPES_KEY";

    protected Recipes(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        servings = in.readInt();
        image = in.readString();
        ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readTypedList(ingredientsList, Ingredients.CREATOR);
stepsList = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readTypedList(stepsList, Steps.CREATOR);
    }

    public Recipes(){}

    public static final Creator<Recipes> CREATOR = new Creator<Recipes>() {
        @Override
        public Recipes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Recipes(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Recipes[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Recipes[size];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getServings() {
        return servings;
    }

    public void setServings(int servings) {
        this.servings = servings;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<Ingredients> getIngredientsList() {
        return ingredientsList;
    }

    public void setIngredientsList(List<Ingredients> ingredientsList) {
        this.ingredientsList = ingredientsList;
    }

    public List<Steps> getStepsList() {
        return stepsList;
    }

    public void setStepsList(List<Steps> stepsList) {
        this.stepsList = stepsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(servings);
        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeTypedList(ingredientsList);
        dest.writeTypedList(stepsList);
    }
}
```